# MySQL - How do I compare values in common between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

TABLE `FRIENDS` - Columns/Values

> ID, FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME
>
> 1, 34, DAMON
>
> 1, 17, RICHARD
>
> 1, 56, DANIEL
>
> 1, 65, CHARLIE
>
> 2, 15, PRISCILA
>
> 2, 17, RICHARD
>
> 2, 45, JOHN
>
> 2, 56, DANIEL

TABLE `USERS` - Columns/Values

> USER_ID, NAME
>
> 1, JUNIOR
>
> 2, SAMANTHA
>
> 15, PRISCILA
>
> 45, JOHN
>
> 56, DANIEL

How do I do a `SELECT` that query all the rows from table `FRIENDS` where `friends.USER_ID = X` and cross reference with all the rows in table `USERS` where the `friends.FRIEND_ID = users.USER_ID`.

Basically I want to query all the friends of a user(from table `FRIENDS`, identified by `friend_id`) that also exist in the table `USERS`(if they exist in the table f`riends.FRIEND_ID` = `users.USER_ID`).

Sorry for the bad english, it's not my native language.

Comment: It's called a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "cross" of data is aptly named a "JOIN". There are different flavors of JOINs, but for you, a simple "inner" join should suffice:

```
SELECT
    f.*
FROM
    FRIENDS f
JOIN
    USERS u
    ON
    r.FRIEND_ID = u.USER_ID
WHERE
    f.FRIEND_ID = ...
```

Comment: It worked great, they way I wanted changing the last clause to f.id, it also worked great with a LEFT JOIN so I could identify who isn't in the table USERS, which I also needed, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to MySQL, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

***First solution :*** using `JOIN`

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM friends f JOIN users u ON u.USER_ID = f.FRIEND_ID 
                           AND u.USER_ID = '?'
```

***Second solution :*** using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM friends f 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM users 
              WHERE USER_ID = f.FRIEND_ID 
                AND USER_ID = '?')
```